# Для чего в файлах с расширением .m присутствует директива @interface?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, интерфейс

Написал и скачал несколько простых приложений в `xcode` в `Cocoa Touch.` Неясно, зачем в файле `viewcontroller.m` присутствует по умолчанию конструкция:

```
@interface ViewController ()

 @end
```

Я её стирал, программы от этого не ломались. Ведь, `.m` - отвечает за реализацию, а не за заголовок. Какие плюшки эта конструкция может дать (отнять)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вкратце:** там можно объявлять скрытые методы, свойства.

**Подробнее:** В *Objective-C* классы можно расширять так называемыми категориями. Сам класс объявляется так:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
}
- (void)publicMethod;
@end
```

А категория так:

```
@interface MyObject (MyObjectCategory)// название категории в скобках
{
}
- (void)privateMethod;
@end
```

Тогда при import'e заготовочного файла с категорией Вам будут доступен дополнительный функционал класса. Реализуется категория обычно в отдельном файле соответственно объявлению:

```
@implementation MyObject (MyObjectCategory)// то же самое название
- (void)privateMethod {
    // do smth
}
@end
```

Если же категория объявлена без имени в *.m-файле, то она должна быть там же и реализована. Получается, дополнительный функционал класса, который она объявляет, остаётся в рамках файла реализации.

Кстати, категории ещё бывают для разделения реализации целого класса. Можно объявить все категории в одном заготовочном файле, чтобы всегда мочь пользоваться всеми возможностями класса, но реализовать категории отдельно, чтобы не тонуть в тоннах кода.